# Linq to SQL, how to get single element without executing the query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

I have stumbled upon an optimization issue and maybe there is a way around it.

Consider that I have the following Entity:

```
public class EntityOne
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Names> Names { get; } 
}
```

And I want to fetch a single Name that matches a specific criteria.
Lets say I create the given model:

```
public class EntityView
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string SingleName {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to fetch the information for the EntityView model in a single query.
This is how I'm doing this so far:

```
var result = db.EntityOnes
.Include(a => a.Names)
.Select(a => new EntityView 
{
  Id = a.Id,
  Name = a.Names.Where(b => b.Criteria == Criteria).Select(b => b.Name).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Is there any way I could go about this in a way that I don't have to execute that FirstOrDefault inside of the main query, and still only fetch a single record for my EntityView model?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Optimizations require concrete context. LinqToSQL and Entity Framework are two  totally different frameworks. Also Entity Framework has two totally different implementations - EF6 and EF Core. Also EF Core query translation/execution varies between different versions. So let start with this: what exact framework are you using? And what exact version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing I would only have one result from my Names, I can just join the IEnumerable result as following:

```
var result = db.EntityOnes
.Include(a => a.Names)
.Select(a => new EntityView 
{
  Id = a.Id,
  Name = string.Join("", a.Names.Where(b => b.Criteria == Criteria).Select(b => b.Name))
}).ToList();
```

This way I would get a single string out of my query and execute a single call to the database

Comment: It's still executing `Where()` and `Select()`. Which isn't actually any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is faster than yours:

```
var result = db.EntityOnes
.Include(a => a.Names)
.Select(a => new EntityView 
{
  Id = a.Id,
  SingleName = a.Names.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Criteria == Criteria)?.Name ?? ""
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip `Where()` and `Select()` inside the query.

```
var result = db.EntityOnes
    .Include(a => a.Names)
    .Select(a => new EntityView 
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        SingleName = a.Names.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Criteria == Criteria)?.Name
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: That is definitely an improvement, but it is still executing one query per EntityOne instead of executing a single query for all of them

Comment: I don't think that's possible.